# UIView detecting touches in only one half of the screen

Tags: objective-c

I am currently working on a 3D OpenGLES-based iPhone Game project and I want to have a view that detect touches so I can then rotate my camera according to the touch gestures.

So here I created a TouchPad class that derives from UIView to record the touch gestures.
Once done I have figured out that only half of the screen is effective. The whole left side.
Whenever i touch the right part of the screen it does not call the -[touchesBegan] method

Here is my class  definition

```
@interface TouchPad : UIView
{
CGPoint fingerMove, originalPosition;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint fingerMove;
@end
```

And here is my class implementation

```
#import "TouchPad.h"

@implementation TouchPad

@synthesize fingerMove;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
        fingerMove = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    std::cout << "called";
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    originalPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
    fingerMove = CGPointMake(currentPosition.x - originalPosition.x, 
                             currentPosition.y - originalPosition.y);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    originalPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
    fingerMove = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    fingerMove = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}

@end
```

And here is how i use it inside my ViewController

```
- (void)prepareGame
{
    game = [[MainGame alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:game.IrrView];
    [game.IrrView release];

    rotationPad = [[TouchPad alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 
                                [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 
                                [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:rotationPad];
    [rotationPad release];

}


- (void)runGame
{
    [game updateMapPattern];
    [game updateCamera :rotationPad.fingerMove];
    [game draw];
}
```

I really want to know how to make the touchPad work in the whole screen and not only the left part of the screen. Maybe there is a conflict with my game view